# Django front-end filter for users to filter model objects

Tags: django, filter, model, frontend

I am trying to create a front-end filter and search system like this link on my Django website:
http://www.habitat.co.uk/sofas-armchairs/sofas-categories/leather-sofas/hyde-leather/shopby/brown/price-655-1500

Here are the following functions that I would like to implement:

- **filter still work after user search for a keyword**, the filter will just continue to narrow the search
- A **listed form** with all the category filters for the user to **click on**
- the **url to change according to the filter** when the user click on a filter like the link listed above

My Django model is just a simple mod like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(SellerAccount)
    media = models.ImageField(blank=True, 
        null=True, 
        upload_to=download_media_location,
        storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PROTECTED_ROOT))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=9.99, null=True,)
    sale_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,
         decimal_places=2, default=6.99, null=True, blank=True)
```

Along with other fields....

My question is, what is the best approach to build the search and filter system that I want? Is there a existing django library that I can utilize?

Comment: Sis you look at django-haystack?

Comment: I haven't but I will now.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need can be made using `django-filter`. More info: http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/